# Nuget update has broken Webmatrix?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, nuget, webmatrix

I've just updated my NuGet.core package using NuGet, and now my site has broken. I'm getting the following error message:

```
Method 'get_IsBindingRedirectSupported' in type 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PackageManager.WebProjectSystem' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_IsBindingRedirectSupported' in type 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration.PackageManager.WebProjectSystem' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Administration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with my web.config not updating? Here's my config:

```
  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NuGet.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.40619.9041" newVersion="2.6.40619.9041" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: What version of WebMatrix do you currently have? 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Nuget and everything was sorted

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error after updating NuGet.Core
Refering to

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/752526/method-get-isbindingredirectsupported-in-type-system-web-webpages-administration-packagemanager-webprojectsystem-from-assembly-system-web-webpages-administration-version-2-0-0-0-culture-neutral

By deleting **System.Web.WebPages.Administration** in References and Rebuilding the solution the problem has been fixed.